# Database design for a lyrics site

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. For my project I want to make a site for lyrics. How to design the database and the relationships?

Here is what I have so far:

**Artist**

- Artist_id
- Artist_name
- Artist_bio
- Artist_thumb

**Albums**

- Album_id
- Artist_id
- Genre_id
- Album_title
- Release_year

**Genre**

- genre_id
- genre_name

**Tracks**

- track_id
- track_title
- album_id

Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks good to me. Except "genre" is spelt "genre", not "genere".

Comment: Apart from the fact that you've mispelt "genre" as "genere", and you seem to have nowhere to store lyrics for track, the latter of which seems to me a fairly fundamental flaw in a lyrics site...

Comment: Actually that's a good point Dominic! :)

Comment: I don't meant to shoot you down or anything, but aren't there already enough lyrics sites out there? http://www.google.com/search?q=lyrics

Comment: I thot I read the RIAA is cracking down on lyrics sites as well as even guitar-tab sites. If you plan to go live to the world w this,  maybe check around to see if you'll get annoyance from them ??

Comment: ya sorry for the typo mistake. well there are already lots of car in road it dosent means car maker stop making cars. as far as RIAA. i m making it for my  school project not for earning money :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly recommend [WWWSQLDesigner](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/) to design your database. Guideline that brianreavis had mentioned are really worthy of listening. Always use correct spelling, use consistent grammar, capitalization and underlining (_). Also you may consider adding multiple genres using a relationship table.

```
  album_genre ( id int, album int, genre int )
```

For album or artist pictures, I recommend you to save them to a folder with their related id's. Observe,

```
 id = 14
 artist = 42
 title = Mask And Mirror
 year = 1994

 thumbnail: /thumbnails/album-14.jpg
```

Comment: I might add one more about WWWSQLDesigner, it also generates table creation queries from your design. Its a very handy tool. You can set it for your site in mere minutes.

Comment: thanks for WWWSQLDesigner its make life easier

Answer (score 14):

1. Be consistent with whether your
   table names are singular or plural. My preference is singular, because then when you're doing multi-table queries, you can refer to a column simply as "`track.id`", rather than "`tracks.id`".
2. Ensure all your table and field
   names are spelled correctly (i.e.
   "genre"); this is something that's a
   pain to change later.
3. Finally, I wouldn't advise prefixing the column names with their parent table's name. It's just redundant.

---

**artist**

- id
- name
- bio
- thumb

**album**

- id
- artist_id
- genre_id
- title
- release_year

**genre**

- id
- name

**track**

- id
- title
- album_id

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a similar response; this man is correct.

Comment: And last but not least: Have a place to put the actual lyrics!

Comment: +1 The singular/plural table naming thing is difficult - yes you get to do `track.id`, but you also do `select * from track`, which reads less naturally than `select * from tracks` in my view.

Comment: ya rite i will take care of singular/plural

Answer (score 7):

Your design looks pretty good. Some additional tables that you may want to add:

- Playlist
- PlaylistTrack
- PlayedTrack

You could add additional fields to the Track table. For example:

- trackSortOrder
- trackYear
- trackGenre
- trackLength
- userRating
- bitRate
- author
- copyright
- numberOfPlays
- lastPlayedDate
- dateAdded

Comment: What does `trackSortOrder` do in the `track` table?

Comment: trackSortOrder would be used to specify the order of the tracks in a single album.

Comment: wht is the use of author as we already adding artist ?
Trackyear is already we added in album release year

Comment: I was thinking some songs are released as singles (i.e. remixes), thus they wouldn't necessarily have an album associated with them. You don't need to create an album entry in order to save a track to the database. When I say author I mean the writer of the song (not always the performer).

Answer (score 3):

Important questions you should be asking yourself while designing

- **What is my requirement!?!** In your case, what all information should my lyrics website have? Should it tell me who actually wrote the song? When was it written? Who all have sung that song etc etc. ***So first thing is you have to define the scope!*** Your Entities and database design will depend on that!
- **What are my entities?**
- **what are the relationships between my main entities?**

Your design might be pretty descent and might work perfectly for your requirement but depending on how much of complexity you are willing to handle (requirement scope!), you might have to take care of things like:

- **Artist and Album actually have many to many relationship**. Many artists might work on same album and of course a single artist will have multiple albums. Your current design will cope up with this but do you want  genreId, title, release_year being duplicated when multiple artists work together for an album?  There is a trade off involved here between creating 1 more table and storing duplicate values. Your current design might be perfect for what you are doing, but just wanted to make sure that you have given it a thought
- In real world, multiple artists collaborate to write a song. Mostly songs are written by someone else and sung by someone else. **You need to define what Artist means to you**. Is it the person who sung the song? Is it someone who wrote the song? Are both artists? If I search for the writer of the song who has not sung a single song, should it return results?
- I dont see a table where you are storing lyrics! But I guess you already know that :)

I can see a few more things which might cause you problems later on, but as I said, I don't know what is the scope of your requirement! :)

Comment: here is wht i did now

i added one more field as Artist_type to know its singer or writer.


now i m not getting how to solve multiple artist thing.
1 track sung by many singer or written  by 2 or more writer

Comment: What if artist is both singer and writer? :) You'll run into lot of issues if u start designing and then think about requirement. I suggest, you first define the scope of your requirement, things like what all information your website will provide etc. You'll have much easier time designing once you have done that. Currently you are trying to hit a moving target.

Comment: can i store writer of the song in another table ?if song have diffrent writer then it create a record in writer table, if not it use same name as artrist... cos if i dont then it will be messy for me

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating multiple different types of objects in a few places -- for instance, it looks like you're trying to create a single `rating` table which applies to albums, artists, and tracks. Consider carefully whether it may be easier to have three separate tables for the three different types of ratings.

Same thing goes for `comment`. Additionally, on that table, your current structure (having a single `comment_id` on an album, artist, or track) would appear to limit each type of object to having a single comment, which doesn't make sense.

For `genre`, `type`, and `thumb`, consider inlining those tables into the parent object. Would it ever make sense to have a single thumb row which is shared between multiple artists, for instance, or would it be easier to just have each artist have a `thumb` path stored directly in it?

Finally, for all of the relationships you've drawn out, you need to define the cardinality of the relationship. For each one, define which table is referring to the other, and "how many" rows in one table can exist for each row in the other one. For instance, the relationship between `album` and `track` is a one-to-many relationship, as each album contains multiple tracks, but each track belongs to one album. Use a notation such as "[crow's foot notation](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~bernatja/crowsfoot.html)" to denote this information.

Answer (score -3):

How about having a separate table for album and a common table which defines the relationship between all the other tables?

Comment: Errr... A single relationships table? May I ask why?

Comment: More foreign Key references could lead to problems... I thought this could simplify the database scheme.

Comment: Less relationships tables make foreign key constraints impossible, which I would have thought leads to more problems. How would a single relationship table be set up? `relationships` with `column1` and `column2`? How readable would joins be? I'd much rather have a table for each type of relationship, than have less tables. It'll make the database schema have more parts, but it'll make it a good deal less complex.